# How to mouse over with Python Selenium 4.3.0?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

ENV

Python 3.10
Selenium 4

Hi,

I use :

```
def findAllByXPath(p_driver, xpath, time=5):
try:
    #return WebDriverWait(p_driver, time).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, (xpath))))
    return WebDriverWait(p_driver, time).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
except Exception as ex:
    print(f"ERROR findAllByXPath : {ex}")

posts = findAllByXPath(p_driver,"//article//a",2)
for index in range(0,len(posts)):
    
    p_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", posts[index])
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 0.8))
    action.move_to_element(posts[index]).perform()
```

To make a mouse over and try to get elements.
I am trying to get the number of comments on an Instagram post from a page profile.
If you pass manually the mouse over a post, the number of comments or likes is displayed.
But when I try to do it in python, it doesn't find the element.
I tried the XPath from console
`$x(//article//li//span[string-length(text())>0]")`

It gives results when I freeze the browser with F8.
action.move_to_element(post).perform() doesn't work? I suspect this version 4.3.0 removed many functions like ActionChains from the Selenium version 3,  didn't it?
How can I extract this element?

Or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How / where is `post` element defined?

Comment: @Prophet I extract list of elements from :

Comment: from nowhere? Can you verify those elements are existing, not null? generally, your question is missing details, debugging details

Comment: @Prophet I extract list of elements from : //article//a and then I loop on each element with an index

Comment: my apologies. I updated the post.

Comment: Thanks. What is `findAllByXPath`? Your local method? Can you show it?

Comment: just added it now

Answer (score 0):

ActionChains works nicely in Selenium v4!
I don't have an Instagram account so I cannot try there but you can see by running this code that `move_to_element()` works and how it works.
The About button (top left corner of stackoverflow homepage) get highlighted.
Remember to don't move your mouse while running of course!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
about_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='https://stackoverflow.co/']")))
actions.move_to_element(about_button)
actions.perform()
```

EDIT: I am using Selenium 4.4.3 and Python 3.10 but it should work with Selenium 4.3.0 as well.